# Is there any support in separating business process modeling questions into a new community?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, area-51

I am wondering whether questions relating to business process modeling notations, styles, etc. that are not written from a programming point of but a business and modeling perspective should be dealt with outside of Stack Overflow. When I look through the questions tagged with [bpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpms), [bpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpm), [business-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-process), for example, I see a lot of questions relating to particular modeling software applications and how to use their syntax or how to configure them to work other applications etc.

I am more interested in different ways of modeling a process or the intricacies of a particular modeling notation such as BPMN, CMMN, DMN and their relationships with each other. In other words, questions that are not about programming even though they could come up when people (developers, business analysts, product owners or anyone else who needs to model aspects of an enterprise) work on software projets.

Would you see any advantages in creating a new community or would you rather keep these types of questions in Stack Overflow and work on proper tagging ?

[I have actually created a new proposal for a business process modeling community in Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121238/business-process-modeling?referrer=IU7kc0WmXuuHw8-vDBM9aw2). I admit, that step was very premature, which I only realised afterwards. If there are any supporters for the idea, feel free to head over the Area51 and discuss it over there.

I would like to discuss:

- bpm-related stuff should moved to a separate community, or
- bpm-related stuff should stay in Stack Overflow (even if not programming-related)

Comment: I have made an edit to include links to the actual tags, removed the PS and PPS as well the meta noise about down votes and made it into something that could be discussed. Please check if that still fits with your goal.

Comment: Thank you for improving my writing style @rene. The post does read better now and it still reflects the goal of my question.